# Upgraded to 4.0.0 after 4.0.0 -BETA1 deployment - now cannot login as superadmin

Tags: reportportal

I had 4.0.0 BETA-1 containers deployed for reportportal and was able to login to UI as superadmin & default users (these are the default created users).

I did not know there was a set of steps that I needed to follow for upgrading. So I did the following :

- stopped and remove the BETA containers.
- docker volume prune
- got the latest docker.compise.yml for 4.0.0 release
- ran the command to start containers.
- All container were up and UI accessible on http://localhost:8080

However, when I try to login using superadmin or 'default' user, I get a message on UI:

> An error occurred when connecting to the server.

What else do I need to cleanup to be able to login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, follow the [official upgrade guide](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/releases/tag/4.0.0)
Make sure all services are UP and running. If you still have any problems, feel free to submit issue on project's GitHub.